# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf' - pip install not solving

Tags: python, pip

Trying to leverage flask_wtf, I've done all of the different suggested steps:

1. pip install flask_wtf
2. pip3 install flask_wtf
3. pip(3) install in each location to ensure that it wasn't due to that

C:\Users\Bob\flask_tutorial>python flask_blog.py -m flask run
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Bob\flask_tutorial\flask_blog.py", line 3, in 
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
File "C:\Users\Bob\flask_tutorial\forms.py", line 1, in 
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'

Comment: try pip install flask-wtf

Answer (score -2):

From the [docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/install/#released-version):

```
pip install -U Flask-WTF
```